# Outside of focusout event I can't get input values

Tags: jquery

As you see I have 3 variable. These are in `focusout` event. If I move these variables to outside of event, it is not working. When `focusout` event happened alert not working because of variables have not values. I want to move them to below `document ready`. How can I fix it? Inputs have default values. Such as 3,5,7 so numeric values

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//I want to move them here
    $("#liste").on("focusout",function () {
        var listeFiyat = $("#liste").val();
        var maliyetFiyat = $("#maliyet").val();
        var indirimliFiyat = $("#indirimli").val();
        if (listeFiyat < maliyetFiyat && listeFiyat.length > 0) {
            window.alert("Liste liste fiyatı, maliyet fiyatından düşük olamaz.");
            $("#liste").css("border", "6px solid red");
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to move the variable assignments outside of the event listener function? Are the three variables meant to be set and then never changed? Or are they changed elsewhere and the `focusout` event simply checks them?

Comment: Ideally it should work, you can use variable declared inside document.ready in any event handler

Answer (score 0):

Hi It is Straight away and it works fine .check the following

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 var listeFiyat;
 var maliyetFiyat;
 var indirimliFiyat;
 $("#liste").on("focusout",function () {
     listeFiyat = $("#liste").val();
     maliyetFiyat = $("#maliyet").val();
     indirimliFiyat = $("#indirimli").val();
    if (listeFiyat < maliyetFiyat && listeFiyat.length > 0) {
        window.alert("Liste liste fiyatı, maliyet fiyatından düşük olamaz.");
        $("#liste").css("border", "6px solid red");
    }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind event on both `inputs`

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
//I want to move them here
    $("#liste,#maliyet").on("focusout",function () {
        var listeFiyat = $("#liste").val();
        var maliyetFiyat = $("#maliyet").val();
        if (listeFiyat*1 < maliyetFiyat*1 && listeFiyat.length > 0) {//convert string to number by *1
            window.alert("Liste liste fiyatı, maliyet fiyatından düşük olamaz.");
            $("#liste").css("border", "6px solid red");
        }

    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/o3ozkq4g/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `parseInt()` for verifying numeric values:

```
var listeFiyat = parseInt($("#liste").val()) || 0;
var maliyetFiyat = parseInt($("#maliyet").val()) || 0;
var indirimliFiyat = parseInt($("#indirimli").val()) || 0;
if (listeFiyat < maliyetFiyat || listeFiyat === 0) {
```